# Passing variable param in form via dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, erb

I have this form:

```
 <tr>
    <% item.inventory_items.each do |product| %>
      <td>
          <%= form_tag("/list_items", method: "post") do %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag(:item_id, item.id) %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag(:inventory_item_id, product.id) %> 
          <%= hidden_field_tag(:shopping_list_id, ShoppingList.first.id) %>
          <%= submit_tag("#{product.price}", class: "btn btn-primary") %>
          <% end %>
      </td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
```

Currently the hidden_field for `shopping_list_id` is being set, as you can see, by `ShoppingList.first.id`. That was really just a placeholder to make sure my form was working. I want the `:user` to be able to select which of their lists to submit this `list_item` to. I'm unsure of the best way to do that. Ideally I'd like to be able to have them hover over the product price and have a drop down of their lists to select from, whereby the form would get the `shopping_list_id` from. How can I best accomplish something like this? I'm using Twitter Bootstrap. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started:

```
<%= select_tag(@user, :shopping_list_id, options_for_select(@user.lists)) %>
```

Comment: Which part is confusing? I can try to clarify.

Comment: I was unaware of select tags, so that's helpful to know about. Question though: why include `:user` like that? When I run that, I get a `can't convert Symbol into Integer` error.